# Revit Custom File Properties

Tags: file, properties, revit, custom-properties

Hello I want to retrieve the custom properties of a file rfa or file rvt (Software Revit file format)

I could during my research came across this link: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api/revit-custom-file-properties/td-p/5533067

but I have found no answer to the question.

Do you have an idea in advance thank you

Comment: I don't believe this is a Revit specific API, but just a regular Win32 API, so you should be able to read it.

Comment: Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: I found a way that adds a property (Google research : https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=win32+api+properties+file+custom+revit,link : http://blog.rodhowarth.com/2008/06/how-to-set-custom-attributes-file.html). I will seek ways to find them.

Comment: Where did you go to add/edit these properties?

Answer (score 1):

Revit uses the [Compound File Binary Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_File_Binary_Format) (CFBF) for his .rvt/.rfa files. You can view the content of a file with [an utility like this one](http://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html). In the specific case of these properties, they must be stored in a property set: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942421.aspx